# Google Analytics Event Tracking on click not responding

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-analytics

Hey I can't seem to get Analytics Event tracking working. Below is what i am working with, it's within PHP but outputs correctly. However when i go onto real time and select the button nothing happens.

```
$prodqoutput = 
'<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img src="' . $logo . '" style="width: 100%;"><br />
        <center><span>' . $excerpt . '</span></center>
        <a href="' . $internalstorelink . '" target="_blank" ga("send", "event", "Out Bound Click", "No Product Button", "'.$brand.'", "'.$title.'");>
            <button style="height: 50px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                View More Products! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>';
```

If anyone can help that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I managed to find nesting quotes is what is needed in this case. Thanks to the guys at https://www.bankholidaysales.co.uk/

Comment: Your example misses the onclick event handler. You cannot simply drop the ga tracking code into the HTML code for the link and expect it to work.

Comment: Came here to say what @EikePierstorff said. You are missing the handler completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'whatever', eventAction: 'submit', eventLabel: 'Whatever', eventValue: 1});
```

your much better off to load this into a js function and trigger that function on click. but the above is the format it needs to be in.

Comment: Thank you, is this something new? All the stuff i found online pointed to what i did.

Comment: no its just really crappily documented, this was my own figuring after hours of testing. I use this code in a function to cover about 1000 events a day, it def works :). Also if you just setup your analytics profile even the real time can take a few days to kick in at first.

Comment: It's still not coming up on analytics, maybe I should leave it a good 24 hours to see if anything comes through then?

Comment: its possible your full code is wrong, id really put this in a js function and call on click, you could also look in developer tools, network tab to see if its sending anything onclick.. . In your code i don't see anything triggering the send, just echoing it wont send it i don't think. Id give it 24 hours and try though.

Comment: I have got this working now but with this insread onClick="ga('send', 'event', ' PDF Downloads', 'Click', 'SEO For Beginners');"... Problem is i can't put it in the php because i need another set of quotes is their anything i can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the last value that You submit in '$title' is a number. Otherwise, it should be. Text variables are Category, Action, and Label. Value need to be a number. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

When I use Google Analytics I prefer to combine with jQuery, like in this example:

```
<a href="' . $internalstorelink . '" class="cta-ga" data-brand="'. $brand .'">
    <button>View More Products!</button>
</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.cta-ga').click(function(){
        label = $(this).attr('data-brand');
        ga('send', 'event', 'Out Bound Click', 'No Product Button', label);
                             //Category          //Action         //Label
     });
});
</script>
```

I created a data variables called "data-label". after I can get this value and send the event with her data.

Comment: This also isn't working. Maybe i have to give it some time? Never had this problem before it's really strange.